# Posible pitfalls when switching from Gmail smtp to Gmail rest api

Tags: smtp, gmail, google-oauth, gmail-api

Google offers two systems for accessing Gmail.  [IMAP and SMTP](https://developers.google.com/gmail/oauth_overview) and a the [Gmail rest api](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/)  Gmail - Scope for SMTP is https://mail.google.com/. However with Gmail rest API, just the required scope (like send, modify) can be used.

What are the main differences between the implementation of these two for sending an email? I've been using SMTP to send the mails without any issues but since that involves having a bigger scope for OAuth2, I want to know if there are any possible risks involved in moving to the API approach.

[Users.messages: send](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send#examples) says there's a restriction on attachment size.

> This method supports an /upload URI and accepts uploaded media with
>   the following characteristics:
>
> Maximum file size: 35MB 
> Accepted Media MIME types: message/rfc822

1. Are there any other differences that I should know about if I start using Gmail APIs instead of using SMTP connection for OAuth2.
2. Also, what is the reasoning behind providing full access as the only possible scope for SMTP/IMAP?

Note: I only requirement is the ability to send emails.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about googles plans to upgrade their smtp servers.  Not something Stack can answer.

Comment: @DalmTo That is a part of the question. I'll remove it. But my question is mainly to know the differences between the API and SMTP implementation. I think that is something Stack can answer. Please let me know if I should reframe it.

Comment: Then it will probably just be to broad or opinion based as we are not Google and cant know the inner workings of their systems please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: To give you some kind of answer I would say SMTP access is old school you can use login and password which means it grants you full access to an account there is really no way to limit that.    Oauth2 is the newer way of doing things more secure way to access Google APIs. Access can be limited by the authentication scope as per the OAuth specifications.  In most cases user changing their password will not remove your access.  However using a gmail scope will nullify all refresh tokens created using a gmail scope will be void after the user changes their password.

Comment: @DalmTo Thanks for your answer. I'm having trouble understanding your last statement - "using a gmail scope will nullify all refresh tokens created using a gmail scope will be void after the user changes their password." Does that mean if I use  full gmail scope and the user changes their password, refresh token for that user will get expired while that is not the case for other scopes?

Comment: give me a second working on a wall of text for you you made me think thanks.  I may tweek your question a little if that's ok.

Comment: The Gmail IMAP and SMTP servers have been extended to support authorization via the industry-standard OAuth 2.0 protocol so I can use token here with the restriction that user needs to approve full scope. If I want to take the consent only for "Sending emails", I need to use google's REST Api. Are there any major differences in the way it handles it? I hope I'm more clear with this.

Comment: Sure, please go ahead.

Answer (score 1):

Using [SMTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) you are directly accessing the mail server located at mail.google.com.  SMTP servers have been around since the 60's they don't have the ability to limit what access you have.  When you log in you have full access to do what ever the mail server in question is capable of.   To login to the SMTP server you need the login (most often email address) and password of the account you wish to access.  Drawback to using the SMTP to connect to Gmail is that if the user changed the password you would then loose access. This day in age it is also considered by most to be bad practice for third party developers to be storing a users login and password in your system.  For example: I would never give any application access to my login and password to Google.  How could you ever prove to me that your system is secure?  If your hacked so am I.

Now on to [Oauth2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749). Oauth came about sometime around 2005 when people wanted to be able to access APIs without having to do something stupid like

> http://awsom.api.com?login=xxx&password=XXX

If memory services it was originally created for the twitter API developers wanted to be able to access  their users twitter account without having to store their login in and password.   Again the main problem with this was the developer in question would then have full access to a users twitter account and if the user or the developer changed the password things would break.

So they created OAuth.  The main features with OAuth are:

1. You can limit access you give an application: (readonly, read write)
2. Password change does not affect access
3. No sharing account credentials with developers of third party apps

So the main point for me as a developer using Oauth with any Google API would be not having to store the login and password of my users and not being affected by a password change.  My users would probably say not having to share their login with me and being able to give my application limited access to their account.

Now back to Gmail. Google made a change about two months ago any refresh token(oauth2) that was created using a Gmail scope will automatically expire when the user changes their password.   To my knowledge this is only Gmail.  so that removes point number two from the features of oauth.

Which should you use is really up to you, assuming you need to be able to send emails.  Then limiting access to read only in your application isn't something you need (point one).  However in my opinion from a security standpoint I would never ask my users to give me their login and password and would always choose oauth2.    Yes SMTP works, will Google shut it down, probably not users have always been given access to the direct SMTP server of their email provider its how applications like outlook work.

as for OAuth support with SMTP unfortunately I haven't done much research into that guess I need to read [RFC 4422](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4422) .  If you can use OAuth with SMTP servers then again I guess the question would have to come down to speed is it faster to access the SMTP server or the REST API server?  I can really think of no differences. Attachments with the Rest API can be tricky.  I may do a bit more digging on the subject.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'll not be asking for the User's password Your last paragraph is what I'm actually looking for. If using REST API might lead to any roadblock or performance issues, I would be more comfortable in using SMTP with OAuth.

Comment: Its the only real difference I can think of.  Oauth with smtp should limit your access,  and not require that you have the users login and password.   https://developers.google.com/gmail/xoauth2_protocol https://developers.google.com/gmail/xoauth2_libraries